# Как получить доступ к терминалу программы на heroku?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, heroku

Есть небольшой телеграмм бот, задеплоен на Heroku.
Мне нужно получить доступ к терминалу программы, для получения возможности отправлять сообщения.

```
 public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

private static String roomId = "";
@Override
public String getBotToken() {
    return "TOKEN";
}

 @Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
}
  @Override
public String getBotUsername() {
    return "NAME";
}
 @Override
public void onUpdatesReceived(List<Update> updates) {
User user = updates.get(0).getMessage().getFrom();
if (updates.get(0).getMessage().getText().equals("/start")) sendMsg(updates.get(0).getMessage().getChatId().toString(),"Привет, "+user.getFirstName()); else {
    System.out.println("ChatId: "+updates.get(0).getMessage().getChatId()+" Username:"+user.getUserName()+" User: " + user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName() + "\n" + "Text: " + updates.get(0).getMessage().getText());
    String messages = updates.get(0).getMessage().getText();
    sendMsg(updates.get(0).getMessage().getChatId().toString(),messages );
    sendMsg(roomId,updates.get(0).getMessage().getFrom().getUserName()+": "+messages);
}
}


@Override
public void onClosing() {

}

public synchronized void sendMsg(String chatId,String s){
    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
    sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
    sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
    sendMessage.setText(s);

    try {
        sendMessage(sendMessage);
    } catch (TelegramApiException ex){
        System.err.println("Exception: "+ex.toString());
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApiContextInitializer.init();
    Thread thread = new Thread(()-> {
        new Bot().sendThread();
    });
    thread.start();
    TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
    try {
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new Bot());
    } catch (TelegramApiRequestException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendThread(){
    String msg = "";
    String roomId = "";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        msg = scanner.nextLine();
            roomId = scanner.nextLine();
        SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
        message.enableMarkdown(true);
        message.setText(msg);
        message.setChatId(roomId);
        try {
            sendMsg(roomId, msg);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Где же взять терминал, если бот задеплоен на Heroku ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никто не читает [документацию](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec)!

```
$ heroku ps:exec
```

Comment: Не буду оправдывать собсвенную тупость, а вам спасибо!)